# how to download hibernate documentation

Tags: hibernate

Hello guys I am really sorry for such question. I could not download hibernate official documentation I was using online html version. Is it possible to download pdf of it?

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

thanks

Comment: I found docs for 3.3 https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/pdf/hibernate_reference.pdf but I need 5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We bundle the HTML version of the documentation with the final release bundles we post to SourceForge and Bintray.

If you look at our blog post [here](http://in.relation.to/2016/12/20/hibernate-orm-526-final-release/), click on the SourceForge or Bintray links and download the release archive.  Inside the release archive is a documentation directory that contains all various documentation guides for that version's release.

While it may be HTML and not PDF, its at least an offline version either way.

Answer (score 2):

It is now version 6.2.6 and methods get quicker so about 15 seconds after typing (your mileage may vary so do `wait Minutes` as logging `23193884 bytes written to file` should give you a final message) note 44ppm is reasonable so 44pps (Pages Per Second) is blindingly fast.

Note for 64bit start with `"C:\Program Files (86)\Mic...` for 32bit it is

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --headless --print-to-pdf="%userprofile%\Desktop\PDFfromCMD.pdf" --no-pdf-header-footer --enable-logging https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html
```

[0428/035904.555:INFO:headless_shell.cc(659)] Written to file C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\PDFfromCMD.pdf.

For a specific earlier version replace `current` with say 6.0 , to see the version list use https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/

I get current pages as a 763 Page PDF

[image]

For current <strike>6.1.4</strike> [updated] 6.1.8 hibernate_search_reference.pdf the pre-compiled version is at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/pdf/hibernate_search_reference.pdf

If you just want parts quickly from Asciidoc source download the zip as mentioned above and use the browser extension see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71181730/10802527

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the official Hibernate's documenation [sources](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/) do not provide us with pdf versions.
But, there is the solution to this issue: we can download a single-html version and convert it by some `html => pdf` tool.
The following solution suits for `Linux`, but you can download according command-line tools for `Windows` as well:

1. Let's create some local folder, go to there and then download the single-html version of the doc with embedded images:

   ```
   wget --no-parent --recursive --level=inf --page-requisites --wait=1 --reject-regex='index.html\?(.*)' https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/
   ```

   (`wget` is a very common pre-installed tool for working with html web pages in Linux; if you are curious about cmd options of the above `wget` command, then you can read about them [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/373075/358073))
2. As `wget` downloaded many dirs and subdirs, we need to go through them and find the folder with the original html file, `Hibernate_User_Guide.html` in this case.
3. Now, we have to convert the downloaded html page to pdf. We'll use `wkhtmltopdf`, which you can download [here](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html):

   ```
   wkhtmltopdf Hibernate_User_Guide.html Hibernate_User_Guide.pdf
   ```

   Or, if you need more configuration options:

   ```
   wkhtmltopdf --encoding utf-8 --page-size A4 --margin-left 5mm --margin-right 5mm --margin-top 5mm --margin-bottom 5mm Hibernate_User_Guide.html Hibernate_User_Guide.pdf
   ```

P.S. The approach, described above, could be used not only for Hibernate, Spring etc. It is the universal solution for converting almost any single-html document pages to PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I have used online HTTP Link to PDF tool, particularly https://www.online-convert.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to download a pdf version of the user guide of Hibernate.
But... ;) ;) you could go to that link 
(http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html) 
which has all the hibernate user guide and print it as a pdf file. Ctrl+P on your browser and select print as pdf (I don't know if all browser have this functionality. Worst case you will need a plugin).
That's what I did and the resulting pdf is pretty decent.

Answer (score 0):

**(Dec 26, 2021)**

I finally found a simple **GUI-based approach** to export the Hibernate documentation as a single PDF file whose table of contents can be read by any PDF viewer software.

First u need to go to the [Hibernate releases page](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/) and download the Zip archive of your desired version to your local machine. All the docs for Hibernate in the raw AsciiDoc document format is located at the root directory `/project/documentation/src/main/asciidoc` of the folder unzipped from your Zip archive. U need the **Asciidoctor PDF Ruby Gem** (an Asciidoctor extension) to convert an AsciiDoc document directly to a PDF document.

Below are all the steps needed to install the extension:

1. The recommended method to install Ruby is using the **Ruby enVironment Manager (RVM)**, follow [all these steps](https://github.com/rvm/rvm#installing-rvm) to install it for your OS, recommended to use Homebrew to install the required dependencies.
2. After the RVM installation in the previous step is complete, run the following CLI command `rvm install ruby --default` to install the latest stable version of Ruby and select this version as the default one.
3. After the Ruby installation in the previous step is complete, run the following CLI command `gem install asciidoctor-pdf` to install the AsciiDoc-to-PDF converter. U might need to follow the [Installation Troubleshooting](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctor-pdf/#getting-started) if there is any error during the installation.
4. Follow [my Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70486172/8138591) to perform the conversion (just ignore the step to create a single pdf file from multiple `.adoc` files). Within the `asciidoc` folder mentioned above, remember to drag a folder of a specific section in the Hibernate doc such as `userguide` or `quickstart` to the VSCode IDE before the conversion.